# C++ WM_NCCALCSIZE not being sent

Tags: c++, windows, api, subclass, edit

I'm trying to center the text in a edit control vertically, after some research I found I have to process the WM_NCCALCSIZE message.
So i've subclassed my edit control, but the WM_NCCALCSIZE message is never sent.

Am I doing something wrong?

***EDIT:***

So i'm processing the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message fine, and I have a 3d border created by passing `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` to `CreateWindowEx`.
But if I disable windows themes by killing the theme service, the border goes away on the control thats processing the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message.
Another control that doesnt process the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message still has the border like normal.

So i'm assuming I'm supposed to be doing somethign in `WM_NCCALCSIZE` that allows me to keep the border? If so what? if not any way to get the border back?

Comment: Please post some code. How do you subclass the edit control? How do you know WM_NCCALCSIZE is never sent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out, `WM_NCCALCSIZE` is sent before the edit control is subclassed.
So i had to superclass the `EDIT` class.

**EDIT:**
Another solution I just thought of would be to subclass it, then call `SetWindowPos` with `SWP_FRAMECHANGED`, this causes it to send the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message.

If anyone has any opinions why one method would be better then the other, please comment :)

Comment: You are totally right. I personally prefer your second option. That is what `SMP_FRAMECHANGED` is for, and I don't like superclassing the standard controls: they look funny in the Spy++.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of tinkering with `WM_NCCALCSIZE` (a very difficult message to manage), why not just reposition your edit control vertically so that the text is at the vertical position you prefer? You can put it inside a white box to provide the white space around it. Alternatively, you can use `EM_SETRECT` to put the text exactly where you want it.

Comment: You didn't say whether you were using a single-line edit control or multi-line, so I just mentioned that as an option in case you were using multi-line.

Comment: High odds for multi-line if vertical positioning is desired, +1.