# Why is WM_NCCALSIZE is not called after the size of WinAPI control is changed?

Tags: c++, winapi, controls

I have a rich edit control who's size is changed after it is created.

I want to customize the control's appearance, so I need to recalculate the size of its client area each time the size of the control is changed. Idea was to change the size of the client area each time the component receives `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message, since MSDN documentation for `WM_NCCALCSIZE` states:

> Sent when the size and position of a window's client area must be calculated. By processing this message, an application can control the content of the window's client area when the size or position of the window changes.

Problem is that the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` is not called after the size of the control is changed (It is called only once when the control is created).

This behavior is not specific to rich edit control. The same is true, e.g. for button controls. It also doesn't matter whether the size is changed before or after the component is shown on the screen.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <richedit.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
    name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
    processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK RichEditProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

WNDPROC richEditOrigProc;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    LoadLibrary(TEXT("msftedit.dll"));

    WNDCLASSEX mainwcex;
    mainwcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    mainwcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    mainwcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    mainwcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    mainwcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    mainwcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    mainwcex.hIcon = NULL;
    mainwcex.hCursor = (HICON)LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    mainwcex.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_MENU);
    mainwcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    mainwcex.lpszClassName = "mainwindow";
    mainwcex.hIconSm = NULL;

    RegisterClassEx(&mainwcex);

    HWND mainWindow = CreateWindowEx(
        NULL,
        "mainwindow",
        NULL,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        100,
        100,
        600,
        400,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    HWND richEditControl = CreateWindowEx(
        NULL,
        "RICHEDIT50W",
        "Rich Edit",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,
        50,
        50,
        100,
        25,
        mainWindow,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    richEditOrigProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtr(richEditControl, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR) RichEditProc);

    // Changes the width of rich edit control from 100 px to 400 px.
    SetWindowPos(richEditControl, NULL, 0, 0, 400, 25,
        SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

    ShowWindow(mainWindow, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        if (!IsDialogMessage(mainWindow, &msg)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK RichEditProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        {
            RECT newClientRect;
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, &newClientRect);
            MapWindowPoints(HWND_DESKTOP, GetParent(hWnd), reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&newClientRect), 2);
            InflateRect(&newClientRect, -3, -3);
            int width = newClientRect.right - newClientRect.left;
            int height = newClientRect.bottom - newClientRect.top;
            if (wParam) {
                NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS* ncParams = reinterpret_cast<NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS*>(lParam);
                ncParams->rgrc[0].left = newClientRect.left;
                ncParams->rgrc[0].top = newClientRect.top;
                ncParams->rgrc[0].right = newClientRect.right;
                ncParams->rgrc[0].bottom = newClientRect.bottom;
                return WVR_HREDRAW;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return CallWindowProc(richEditOrigProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

In this example, it is evident that while the total size of the rich edit control is changed, it's client area is not recalculated and corresponds to its initial size.

What is the correct way to resize the client area of custom control, to reflect the change in its total size.

Comment: Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539711/c-wm-nccalcsize-not-being-sent).

Comment: I suggest to learn from the existing solutions for this kind of problem, e. g. [XP Theme Support for Rich Edit and Custom Controls](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/dislog/miscellaneous/article.php/c8729/XP-Theme-Support-for-Rich-Edit-and-Custom-Controls.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do things when a control is resized, you should be catching `WM_SIZE`, not `WM_NCCALCSIZE`.

The purpose of `WM_NCCALCSIZE` is to allow (for example) a captioned window to recalculate the size of its client area when the height of the caption bar changes. (Users can adjust this through the control panel, or at least they used to.)  I would expect `WM_NCCALCSIZE` to be sent when the control is created though, bit of a mystery that.

WM_SIZE is fully documented at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also: I don't see you actually resizing that control anywhere in your code...

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using WM_NCCALCSIZE you should be able to force it with SetWindowPos by specifying the SWP_FRAMECHANGED flag.

Answer (score 0):

`WM_NCCALSIZE` message was handled the wrong way. Instead of setting the coordinates of new client rectangle to the `rgrc[0]` rectangle of `NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS`, only increment/decrement relative to the control's total bounds should be set. Those increment/decrement values specify the size of the non-client area, i.e. the margins of the client area.

After the control's size is changed, the size of client area is automatically adjusted relative to the new control's bounds.

For example, this code sets the client area with top/bottom margins of `3 px` and left/right margins of `50 px`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <richedit.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
    name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
    processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK RichEditProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

WNDPROC richEditOrigProc;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    LoadLibrary(TEXT("msftedit.dll"));

    WNDCLASSEX mainwcex;
    mainwcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    mainwcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    mainwcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    mainwcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    mainwcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    mainwcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    mainwcex.hIcon = NULL;
    mainwcex.hCursor = (HICON)LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    mainwcex.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_MENU);
    mainwcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    mainwcex.lpszClassName = "mainwindow";
    mainwcex.hIconSm = NULL;

    RegisterClassEx(&mainwcex);

    HWND mainWindow = CreateWindowEx(
        NULL,
        "mainwindow",
        NULL,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        100,
        100,
        600,
        400,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    HWND richEditControl = CreateWindowEx(
        NULL,
        "RICHEDIT50W",
        "Rich Edit",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,
        50,
        50,
        100,
        25,
        mainWindow,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    richEditOrigProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtr(richEditControl, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR) RichEditProc);

    // Changes the width of rich edit control from 100 px to 400 px.
    SetWindowPos(richEditControl, NULL, 0, 0, 400, 25,
        SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

    ShowWindow(mainWindow, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        if (!IsDialogMessage(mainWindow, &msg)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK RichEditProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        {
            if (wParam) {
                NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS* ncParams = reinterpret_cast<NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS*>(lParam);
                ncParams->rgrc[0].left += 50;
                ncParams->rgrc[0].top += 3;
                ncParams->rgrc[0].right -= 50;
                ncParams->rgrc[0].bottom -= 3;
                return WVR_HREDRAW;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return CallWindowProc(richEditOrigProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```